# Refreshing page on click of a button

Tags: javascript

I would like to refresh the current page when a button is clicked.

Using JavaScript, I have the following:

```
<button type="button" onClick="refreshPage()">Close</button>

<script>
    function refreshPage() {
        // What do I put here?
    } 
</script>
```

What would to code look like to refresh the current page?

Answer (score 52):

```
<button type="button" onClick="refreshPage()">Close</button>

<script>
function refreshPage(){
    window.location.reload();
} 
</script>
```

or

```
<button type="button" onClick="window.location.reload();">Close</button>
```

Comment: window.location.reload() not working for IE 10
can you help ?

Answer (score 14):

There are several ways to reload the current page using a button or other trigger. The examples below use a button click to reload the page but you can use a text hyperlink or any trigger you like.

```
<input type="button" value="Reload Page" onClick="window.location.reload()">

<input type="button" value="Reload Page" onClick="history.go(0)">

<input type="button" value="Reload Page" onClick="window.location.href=window.location.href">
```

Answer (score 4):

Works for every browser.

```
<button type="button" onClick="Refresh()">Close</button>

<script>
    function Refresh() {
        window.parent.location = window.parent.location.href;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This question actually is not JSP related, it is HTTP related. you can just do:

> window.location = window.location;

Comment: Aren't you in turn confusing HTTP with JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest `<a href='page1.jsp'>Refresh</a>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onclick=location=URL>Refresh</button>
```

Small hack.

Comment: @RufusVS Not needed.

Answer (score 0):

**Develop Refresher App!** 
*Copy and run!*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Refresher App</title>
    <style>
        body {
            text-align: center;
            background-color: brown;
        }
        #container {
            color: white;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <h1 id="counter">0</h1>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    var counter = document.getElementById("counter").textContent;
    //For Counter
    setInterval(function () {
        counter++;
        document.getElementById("counter").textContent = counter;
    }, 1000);
    //For Reload
    setInterval(function () {
        window.location.reload();
    }, 10000)
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you need all that CSS to answer the question? And the code here is refreshing on timeout while the OP is asking about button refresh. Could edit/simplify the code to contain only what it's needed and answer exactly what OP is asking? Posting a jsfiddle helps a lot as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily add Location reload() Method

```
// What do I put here?
   location.reload();
```