# How to fix information inside text box from disappearing upon submit and calculation?

Tags: php, html

This code gets to and from info and calculates distance, the only problem is that once the user presses submit button the to and from info disappears from the text boxes that the users put that information in.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" name"lion" id"blue"  >  
        <p class="distanceTotal">
            <div id="d">
                <p>
                    <b>Adress From<b><input type="text" name="addrFrom" id="fred" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label>Adress To</label><b>
                    <input type="text" name="addrTo" id="chris" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input type="text" name="distanceTotal" id="distanceTotal" 
                    value="<?php if (!empty($distanceTotal)) { ?>
                    <?php if ($success = true) {  echo ''. $distanceTotal; } ?><?php } ?>" />
                </p>
                <b><b>Total Miles<b><b>
                <p>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Calculate Distance"  />
                </p>
            </div>
        </p>
    </form>
</body>
```

`

My goal is for the user to sustain that info even after the user presses submit!

Here is the PHP I used to come up with the total distance ("distanceTotal").

```
?php>
function getDistance($addressFrom, $addressTo, $unit){
//Change address format
$formattedAddrFrom = str_replace(' ','+',$addressFrom);
$formattedAddrTo = str_replace(' ','+',$addressTo);

//Send request and receive json data
$geocodeFrom = 
file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?
address='.$formattedAddrFrom.'&sensor=false');
$outputFrom = json_decode($geocodeFrom);
$geocodeTo = 
file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?
address='.$formattedAddrTo.
'&sensor=false');
$outputTo = json_decode($geocodeTo);

//Get latitude and longitude from geo data
$latitudeFrom = $outputFrom->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
$longitudeFrom = $outputFrom->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
$latitudeTo = $outputTo->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
$longitudeTo = $outputTo->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;

//Calculate distance from latitude and longitude
$theta = $longitudeFrom - $longitudeTo;
$dist = sin(deg2rad($latitudeFrom)) * sin(deg2rad($latitudeTo)) +   
cos(deg2rad($latitudeFrom)) * cos(deg2rad($latitudeTo)) * 
cos(deg2rad($theta));
$dist = acos($dist);
$dist = rad2deg($dist);
$miles = $dist * 60 * 1.8515;
$unit = strtoupper($unit);
if ($unit == "K") {
    return round($miles * 1.609344, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP).' km';
} else if ($unit == "N") {
    return round($miles * 0.8677, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP).'';
} else {
    return round ($miles).'';
}
}

if (!empty($_POST['addrFrom']) && !empty($_POST['addrTo'])) { 
    $addressFrom = htmlspecialchars($_POST['addrFrom']);
    $addressTo = htmlspecialchars($_POST['addrTo']);
    $distanceTotal = getDistance($addressFrom, $addressTo, "N");
    $distanceTotal = sprintf('%0.2f',round($distanceTotal,2));
    $success = true; 
    } 

?>
```

Comment: please change the CAPS to lowercase, it's considered as yelling. I don't like getting yelled at, do you?

Comment: you have a few errors btw, one will always be true, the others are typos to which I voted to close as.

Comment: I inserted the code but the info still disappears and know the answer doesn't appear either I'm kinda of wet behind the ears and new to the platform I didn't realize I was yelling did not mean any harm but how do I validate this or integrate the suggest code with what I have?

Comment: I edited my answer to show you a fuller version of what you are looking for. Let me know if you have any problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here is a fuller version of what you need:

```
<?php

function getDistance($addressFrom, $addressTo, $unit){
//Change address format
$formattedAddrFrom = str_replace(' ','+',$addressFrom);
$formattedAddrTo = str_replace(' ','+',$addressTo);

//Send request and receive json data
$geocodeFrom =
file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?
address='.$formattedAddrFrom.'&sensor=false');
$outputFrom = json_decode($geocodeFrom);
$geocodeTo =
file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?
address='.$formattedAddrTo.'&sensor=false');
$outputTo = json_decode($geocodeTo);

//Get latitude and longitude from geo data
$latitudeFrom = $outputFrom->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
$longitudeFrom = $outputFrom->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
$latitudeTo = $outputTo->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
$longitudeTo = $outputTo->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;

//Calculate distance from latitude and longitude
$theta = $longitudeFrom - $longitudeTo;
$dist = sin(deg2rad($latitudeFrom)) * sin(deg2rad($latitudeTo)) +
cos(deg2rad($latitudeFrom)) * cos(deg2rad($latitudeTo)) *
cos(deg2rad($theta));
$dist = acos($dist);
$dist = rad2deg($dist);
$miles = $dist * 60 * 1.8515;
$unit = strtoupper($unit);
if ($unit == "K") {
return round($miles * 1.609344, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP).' km';
} else if ($unit == "N") {
return round($miles * 0.8677, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP).'';
} else {
return round ($miles).'';
}
}
$distanceTotal = null;
$addressFrom = null;
$addressTo = null;

if(!empty($_GET['addrFrom'])) { $addressFrom = $_GET['addrFrom']; }
if(!empty($_GET['addrTo'])) { $addressTo = $_GET['addrTo']; }
if(!empty($_GET['distanceTotal'])) { $distanceTotal = 
$_GET['distanceTotal']; }

if (!empty($_GET['addrFrom']) && !empty($_GET['addrTo'])) {
$distanceTotal = getDistance($addressFrom, $addressTo, "N");
$distanceTotal = sprintf('%0.2f',round($distanceTotal,2));
}
$success = false;

?>
<?php

$selected='';

function get_options($select)
{   

$rate=array('Economic Rate'=>3.00,'Standard Rate'=>4.00,'Express 
Rate'=>5.00,'Quantumtheory'=>6.00);
$option='3.00';

foreach ($rate as $key_rate => $value_rate)

{
if($select==$value_rate)
{
     $option.='<option value="'.$value_rate.'" 
selected>'.$key_rate.'</option>';
}
else
{       
     $option.='<option value="'.$value_rate.'">'.$key_rate.'</option>'; 
}

}
return $option;
}

if(isset($_POST['rate']))

{

$selected=number_format((float)$_POST ['rate'], 2,'.','');


}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>

<body>
<div align="center">
<script>
if(typeof window.history.pushState == 'function') {
    window.history.pushState({}, "Hide", "<?php echo 
$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>");
}
</script>
<form method="get" name"lion" id"blue" action="overflow.php" >  
<p class="distanceTotal">
<div id="d">

<p><b>Adress From<b>
<input type="text" name="addrFrom" id"fred" value="<?php echo $addressFrom; 
?>" /></p>
<p><label>Adress To</label><b>
<input type="text" name="addrTo" id="chris" value="<?php echo $addressTo;   
?>" 
/></p>
<label>Total Miles<label><b> 
<input type="text" id="distanceTotal" name="distanceTotal" value="<?php echo 
$distanceTotal; ?>" >

<p><input type="hidden" name="success" value="false" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Calculate Distance" /></p>

</div>
</p>
</form>

<form method="post" name"tiger" id="black" />
<p>
<div>

<select name="rate">
<option value="<?php echo get_options($selected); ?>" /></option>
</select>
<input type='submit' id='submit_2' name="calc_2" value='Submit' />
<input type="text" id="rateTotal" name="rat" width="110px" value="<?php echo 
$selected; ?>" /><b><b><label>Per Mile</label>

</div>  
</p>
</form>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you missed something here,  a few actually.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Yes, there is a lot that needs to be done to have the code posted actually work, but that does answer the question. He stated the code works, so this must not be the actual code, right?

Comment: This will retain only the distanceTotal information. Both of the $_POST variables will need to be validated. Here is some info on that - https://www.w3schools.com/PhP/php_form_validation.asp and https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/sanitize-and-validate-data-with-php-filters--net-2595

Comment: I've originally got the answer from the start, the only problem is that once the user presses the submit button the address to and address from info disappears from the text boxes that the users put that information in.This is still happening despite the changes only now the I am not getting the answer as well, I didn't include the PHP I used to get that answer in the post it was kinda lengthy should I post that as well?

Comment: OK, I put it in one big file and I believe it is working they way you would like. Again, don't forget to validate any user input (all of the $_POST fields). There are always multiple ways to code these things and follow best practice, but this will at least get you started!

Comment: Yes that's it your the best I really do appreciate it I was stuck, I'll keep all of the other notes you added in mind next up is validating the user input I'm going to go over that link looks like something I really need to learn once again thanks your the best.

Comment: That sounds good. Glad I could help! Let me know if anything comes up. Could you please accept this as the correct answer (the green checkmark)?

Comment: This is definitely what I was looking for but, I forgot to mention that I needed the page to be able to reload and refresh the browser if the user chooses to do so, I eventually noticed it doesn't do that, what could I add, take away or adjust to enable the (reload this page) browser function, you know the little circular arrow that refreshes the page just in case the user wanted to refresh the page, I apologize I should have mention this from the start :) once again thanks a lot this is the correct answer were is the (green check mark) located I'm a newbie?

Comment: I edited the answer and added another form that will set the $success variable to false, thereby clearing the form. You could also do that with javascript if all you wanted to do was refresh the page ( see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480945/refreshing-page-on-click-of-a-button ). To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green (see screenshot below)

Comment: Sorry, no screenshot!

Comment: My objective is for the user to be able to use the (reload this page) button in the upper left hand area of the browser, the little circular arrow in the very top left hand corner of the browser to refresh and clear data if they needed to and do so without getting the confirm form re-submission message.

Comment: You are probably looking for the post-redirect-get pattern (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get). I will show you a working sample in another answer that will do what you are asking.

Comment: It worked with a few changes thanks a lot, my next challenge is get it to work in combination with a second form that's on the same page when I combined them and press submit on the second form the information from the first form disappears...

Comment: Now my objective is to figure out how to sustain the information in second form as well unless the user decides to reloads and refresh the page with the round circular arrow in the upper left hand corner of the browser, in that case all of the information disappearing would be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can post the form to another file, process the info and have it redirect back to the form with GET variables. Those can be hidden on refresh in HTML5 browsers. Here is the form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php

$success = false;
$distanceTotal = null;
$addressFrom = null;
$addressTo = null;

if(isset($_GET['success'])) {
  if($_GET['success']==true) {
    $success = true;
  }
}

if($success == true) {
  if(!empty($_GET['addrFrom'])) { $addressFrom = $_GET['addrFrom']; }
  if(!empty($_GET['addrTo'])) { $addressTo = $_GET['addrTo']; }
  if(!empty($_GET['distanceTotal'])) { $distanceTotal = $_GET['distanceTotal']; }
  $success = false;
}
?>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
        if(typeof window.history.pushState == 'function') {
            window.history.pushState({}, "Hide", "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>");
        }
    </script>
    <form method="POST" name="lion" id="blue" action="calculate.php">
      <p class="distanceTotal">
        <div id="d">
          <p>
            <label><b>Adress From</b></label>
            <input type="text" name="addrFrom" id="fred" value="<?php echo $addressFrom; ?>" />
          </p>
          <p>
            <label><b>Adress To</b></label>
            <input type="text" name="addrTo" id="chris" value="<?php echo $addressTo; ?>" />
          </p>
            <label><b>Total Miles</b></label>
            <input type="text" name="distanceTotal" id="distanceTotal" value="<?php echo $distanceTotal; ?>" />
          <p>
            <input type="hidden" name="success" value="true" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Calculate Distance"/>
          </p>
        </div>
      </p>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

and here is the file it posts to (in this case I named the file calculate.php and placed it in the same folder):

```
<?php
function getDistance($addressFrom, $addressTo, $unit){
//Change address format
$formattedAddrFrom = str_replace(' ','+',$addressFrom);
$formattedAddrTo = str_replace(' ','+',$addressTo);

//Send request and receive json data
$geocodeFrom =
file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$formattedAddrFrom.'&sensor=false');
$outputFrom = json_decode($geocodeFrom);
$geocodeTo =
file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$formattedAddrTo.'&sensor=false');
$outputTo = json_decode($geocodeTo);

//Get latitude and longitude from geo data
$latitudeFrom = $outputFrom->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
$longitudeFrom = $outputFrom->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
$latitudeTo = $outputTo->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
$longitudeTo = $outputTo->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;

//Calculate distance from latitude and longitude
$theta = $longitudeFrom - $longitudeTo;
$dist = sin(deg2rad($latitudeFrom)) * sin(deg2rad($latitudeTo)) +
cos(deg2rad($latitudeFrom)) * cos(deg2rad($latitudeTo)) *
cos(deg2rad($theta));
$dist = acos($dist);
$dist = rad2deg($dist);
$miles = $dist * 60 * 1.8515;
$unit = strtoupper($unit);
if ($unit == "K") {
    return round($miles * 1.609344, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP).' km';
} else if ($unit == "N") {
    return round($miles * 0.8677, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP).'';
} else {
    return round ($miles).'';
}
}

$distanceTotal = null;
$addressFrom = null;
$addressTo = null;

if(!empty($_POST['addrFrom'])) { $addressFrom = $_POST['addrFrom']; }
if(!empty($_POST['addrTo'])) { $addressTo = $_POST['addrTo']; }
if(!empty($_POST['distanceTotal'])) { $distanceTotal = $_POST['distanceTotal']; }

if (!empty($_POST['addrFrom']) && !empty($_POST['addrTo'])) {
    $distanceTotal = getDistance($addressFrom, $addressTo, "N");
    $distanceTotal = sprintf('%0.2f',round($distanceTotal,2));
    }
    $success = false;
    //edit this location - change myfile to your file name
    header("Location: myfile.php?success=true&addrFrom=".$addressFrom."&addrTo=".$addressTo."&distanceTotal=".$distanceTotal);
  exit();


?>
```

This will need some work to handle errors (like just redirect back to the form with no get parameters if the form posts empty variables - as well as handling any errors from the google api), but it will do what you are asking for.